# Count Rotations in unity 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a game in which the character falls down on a slope and is constantly rotating clockwise at a fixed rotation. If it lands on it's feet it jumps.

The question is how to count a full spin(360) after touching the ground and how to multiply the jumping power for each complete spin, for ex. if the player manages to have a full spin and lands on its feet then the jumpower will be multiplied by X, if it manages two spins it will be multiplied by Y... and so on, but when it fails and touches the ground with other parts of the body I need to also reset the jumppower to initial value.

I tried using eulerAngles, but it doesn't work... Also I want to have a counter on screen that can show the user how many rotations has got after jumping and resetting when touching the ground, if its possible, I am new into unity and any help will be deeply appreciated.

**This is the code that I used for counting rotations(also found on stackoverflow)**:

```
private void Start()
{
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    previousRollAngle = rigidBody.transform.eulerAngles.x;
}
private void FixedUpdate()        
{

    IsTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, GroundLayer);
    if (IsTouchingGround)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = transform.up * JumpPower;
    }

    //rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, JumpPower);
    // direction = rigidBody.transform.direction
    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower),ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    //countspins
    if (rollDegree >= 360)
    {
        rollDegree = rollDegree - 360;
        leftSpins++;
    }
    else if (rollDegree <= -360)
    {
        rollDegree = rollDegree + 360;
        rightSpins++;
    }
    rollDegree = rollDegree + (rigidBody.transform.eulerAngles.x - previousRollAngle);
    previousRollAngle = rigidBody.transform.eulerAngles.x;

    if (rightSpins == 1)
    {
        JumpPower = JumpPower * 3;
    }
}
```

**And this is the code that I used for rotating the player:**

```
void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = Spin;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = CtrSpin;
    }
```

Also I added an image with an example to be more clear
[image: Example]

Comment: You've explained what you want to do, and you're showing the code you wrote, but what's the actual _problem_ you need to solve that you're asking SO for help with? Is your `if (rollDegree >= 360)` not triggering?

Comment: yes,, the jump power is stiil the same no matter how many spins

Comment: and I can't figure out how to display the spins on UI

Comment: Please reread my comment: don't tell me, tell _everyone_ by updating your post. Right now you're not actually asking for help with a problem, you've just said what you wanted to do, and you're showing code, but there's no _question_ for stackoverflow to answer. [What's is the problem?](/help/how-to-ask). And remember "it doesn't work" is an opinion, it's working exactly as you programmed it to, so (1) what did you expect it to do, (2) what does it do instead, and (3) what concrete things have you already tried (tried different code? show all of them and talk about what that did, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know if you've managed to solve this, but for testing purposes you can use unity's `Debug.Log();` and check the console to figure out the number of spins, as for hooking up a UI element to display the spins you first have to add a canvas  to your game, and on that canvas add a text mesh pro element, in your script add the `using TMPro;` at the top and then add this `[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI spins;` then in the fixedupdate method just assign your spins object like so
`spins = "Spins: " + rightSpins;`

drag and drop your TMPro object in the hierarchy onto the Game object which has your script in the inspector.

Now as for the collisions was wondering why you were using fixedupdate instead of OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionExit2D
Also try moving the logic u have from fixed update to update instead.

Here is what i use to calculate the number of spins on a 2D character

`

```
private float _angle;

private SpinDisplay _displayScript;

bool _isGrounded;

void Update()
{

    if(!_isGrounded)
        CalculateSpins();

}

private void CalculateSpins()
{
    var currentRight = transform.right;
    _angle += Vector2.SignedAngle(_previousRight, currentRight);
    _previousRight = currentRight;
    if (Mathf.Abs(_angle) >= 300f)
    {
        _displayScript.IncrementSpin();
        _angle -= 300f * Mathf.Sign(_angle);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    _isGrounded = true; 
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    _previousRight = transform.right;
    _angle = 0;
    _isGrounded = false;
}
```

`

The spin display just updates the text mesh pro objects text, also i use 300 instead of 360 for personal preference, this is i found that rotating a whole 360 for a spin was a bit irritating for the player, but u can switch it to 360, basically all this script does is checks for the number of spins when you are not colliding with the ground, when you do collide you'd want to reset things so that the next time you are not colliding (if in the air for instance) you'd start calculating the next set of spins, in your particular case, in the if statement of the `CalculateSpins()` method, you can update your jump force or any other variables.

Comment: Hello, i managed to count the spins with the code below, but it doesn’t work properly, i mean either it doesn’t reset the spins after the jump, either it doesn’t reset the spin counter. 
Your code seems perfect for what i need but also i don’t know exactly how to implement it in my code and i don’t know how to insert in the CalculateSpins() method so i can reset the spin counter properly and count the nect set of spins as you said.

Comment: I also used Physics2D.Overlapcircle, and i don’t realy now how to implement the OnCollisionEnter2d….  I used two empty game objects attached to player and on is for jumping when touching ground and one for reseting spins…. The idea is that if the Player touches the ground with the rest of it’s body it doesn’t jump and only jumps when it touches with it’s legs and also the jump power has to reset if it doesn’t jump on it’s feet.

Comment: For example: The player rotates 1 spin and the jumpPower has to increase by X and also at the same time the spin counter has to reset after the jump, because now in my code it resets at the same time as it increases the jumppower and the jumppower remains the same because the spin counter becomes 0 at the same time.
I will post below my code and i appreciate very much for your answer, my code is a mess and i am a complete beginner, and this is the only problems i have to solve to finish this game’s “physics

Comment: I would appreciate any advice on how to solve this and how can i apply your code, thank you very much!

Comment: i will post my code in a new answer because it's too long

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountSpins : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Groundcheck script;
    //Ground check for SpinCounter RESET
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
    private bool IsTouchingGroundSpinReset;

    // keeps the last frames right vector
    private Vector2 _previousRight;

    // keeps the already rotated angle
    private float _angle;
    public int spinCounter;
    public Text countText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        _previousRight = transform.right;
        // countText = GetComponent<Text>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {

        // get this frame's right vector
        var currentRight = transform.right;

        // compare it to the previous frame's right vector and sum up the delta angle
        _angle += Vector2.SignedAngle(_previousRight, currentRight);

        // store the current right vector for the next frame to compare
        _previousRight = currentRight;

        // did the angle reach +/- 360 ?
        if (Mathf.Abs(_angle) >= 360f && IsTouchingGroundSpinReset == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Completed Full Spin!");


            // if _angle > 360 subtract 360
            // if _angle < -360 add 360
            _angle -= 360f * Mathf.Sign(_angle);
            //display spins
            //countText.text = spinCounter.ToString();
            spinCounter++;

        }

        Debug.Log($"spinCounter = {spinCounter}");

        if (spinCounter == 0)
        {
            script.JumpPower = 11f;
        }
        if (spinCounter == 1)
        {
            script.JumpPower = 15;
        }
        if (spinCounter == 2)
        {
            script.JumpPower = 20;
        }
        if (spinCounter == 3)
        {
            script.JumpPower = 25;
        }

        IsTouchingGroundSpinReset = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, GroundLayer);
        if(IsTouchingGroundSpinReset == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(myDelay());
        }
        IEnumerator myDelay()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
            if (IsTouchingGroundSpinReset)
            {

                spinCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        
        Debug.Log($"JumpPOWER = {script.JumpPower}");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the code for counting spins

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Groundcheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
    private bool IsTouchingGround;
    public float JumpPower;
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    public GameObject Player;

    float rollDegree = 0, previousRollAngle;
    int leftSpins = 0;
    int rightSpins = 0;

    // public if you want to drag your text object in there manually
    int spinCounter;

    private void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }
    private void Update()
    {

        IsTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, GroundLayer);
        if (IsTouchingGround)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = transform.up * JumpPower;
        }

        //rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, JumpPower);
        // direction = rigidBody.transform.direction
        // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower),ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        //countspins

        //display spins
        //countText.text = rightSpins.ToString();

    }



}
```

Comment: this is the code for groundcheck and jumping...as i said it is a total mess

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32263806)